# C#: What is the default value of an uninstantiated object?

Tags: c#, class, oop

I have a quick question about default values in c#.

What us the default value of an object when not instantiated?

Here is an example:

```
public class Example
{
  public Example() { Console.WriteLine("Content!"); }
}

public class MainClass
{
  // obj = ???
  Example obj;
}
```

Comment: Well you have the example ready. Why not do a test?

Comment: Why do you ask here instead of using Google? First Google result for `c# default value`: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx

Comment: You don't have an "uninstantiated object". You have an uninitialized variable.

Comment: public static T GetDefault<T>(T value) where T : class => default(T);  defautl value of object is always null

Comment: This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: Local variables contain *trash*; uninitialized fields are zero-initialized

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rule is simple

- Local variables contain are not initialized at all, and thus contain trash.

> A local variable is not automatically initialized and thus has no
>   default value.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691170(v=vs.71).aspx

- Fields are initialized by their *default values* (zeros):

> The initial value of a field, whether it be a static field or an
>   instance field, is the default value

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645756(v=vs.71).aspx

For instance

```
 public class Example {
   bool m_Bool;       // default value == false
   int m_Int;         // default value == 0
   double m_Double;   // default value == 0.0
   string m_Text      // default value == null;
   Example m_Example; // default value == null;

   public void Test() {
     bool boolValue;     // contains trash, must be initialized before using
     int intValue;       // contains trash, must be initialized before using
     double doubleValue; // contains trash, must be initialized before using 
     string textValue;   // reference to trash, must be initialized before using   
     Example example;    // reference to trash, must be initialized before using   
     ...
   } 
 }
```